# How to copy data from one HDFS to another HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, sqoop

I have two HDFS setup and want to copy (not migrate or move) some tables from HDFS1 to HDFS2. How to copy data from one HDFS to another HDFS? Is it possible via Sqoop or other command line?

Answer (score 42):

DistCp (distributed copy) is a tool used for copying data between clusters. It uses MapReduce to effect its distribution, error handling and recovery, and reporting. It expands a list of files and directories into input to map tasks, each of which will copy a partition of the files specified in the source list.

Usage: `$ hadoop distcp <src> <dst>`

example: `$ hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/file1 hdfs://nn2:8020/file2`

`file1` from `nn1` is copied to `nn2` with filename `file2`

Distcp is the best tool as of now. Sqoop is used to copy data from relational database to HDFS and vice versa, but not between HDFS to HDFS.

More info:

- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html
- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp2.html

There are two versions available - runtime performance in `distcp2` is more compared to `distcp`

Comment: I want to get huge files from mainFrame to hdfs.. what approach do u suggest? I can copy them to unix and parse them using phython.. if they were small files.. kindly suggest

Comment: @vikrantrana - This might help https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/10/how-sqoop-1272-can-help-you-move-big-data-from-mainframe-to-apache-hadoop/

Comment: @ Avinash Reddy. Thanks.It seems that link suggesting to use sqoop to import mainframe file data from pds. I guess it will landed in binary form only thereafter we need to convert it to ascii and parse it on hdfs to make it delimited.. Is that the approach or we can do something else. Kindly suggest

Comment: @vikrantrana I am not familiar with Mainframe data formats. Since you were referring to moving huge files, It is good to land the data and then convert by leveraging parallel processing effectively.

Answer (score 20):

Hadoop comes with a useful program called `distcp` for copying large amounts of data to and from Hadoop Filesystems in parallel. The canonical use case for distcp is for transferring data between two HDFS clusters.
If the clusters are running identical versions of hadoop, then the hdfs scheme is appropriate to use.

```
$ hadoop distcp hdfs://namenode1/foo hdfs://namenode2/bar
```

The data in `/foo` directory of namenode1 will be copied to /bar directory of namenode2. If the `/bar` directory does not exist, it will create it. Also we can mention multiple source paths.

Similar to `rsync` command, distcp command by default will skip the files that already exist. We can also use `-overwrite` option to overwrite the existing files in destination directory. The option `-update` will only update the files that have changed.

```
$ hadoop distcp -update hdfs://namenode1/foo hdfs://namenode2/bar/foo
```

`distcp` can also be implemented as a MapReduce job where the work of copying is done by the maps that run in parallel across the cluster. There will be no reducers.

If trying to copy data between two HDFS clusters that are running different versions, the copy will process will fail, since the RPC systems are incompatible. In that case we need to use the read-only HTTP based HFTP filesystems to read from the source. Here the job has to run on destination cluster.

```
$ hadoop distcp hftp://namenode1:50070/foo hdfs://namenode2/bar
```

50070 is the default port number for namenode's embedded web server.

Answer (score 13):

`distcp` is used for copying data to and from the hadoop filesystems in parallel. It is similar to the generic `hadoop fs -cp` command. In the background process, `distcp` is implemented as a MapReduce job where mappers are only implemented for copying in parallel across the cluster. 
**Usage:**

- copy one file to another

  `% hadoop distcp file1 file2`
- copy directories from one location to another

  `% hadoop distcp dir1 dir2`

If `dir2` doesn't exist then it will create that folder and copy the contents. If `dir2` already exists, then `dir1` will be copied under it. `-overwrite` option forces the files to be overwritten within the same folder. `-update` option updates only the files that are changed.

- transferring data between two HDFS clusters

  `% hadoop distcp -update -delete hdfs://nn1/dir1 hdfs://nn2/dir2`

`-delete` option deletes the files or directories from the destination that are not present in the source.

Comment: I am getting while trying to copy ... Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

Try [dtIngest](https://www.datatorrent.com/download/), it's developed on top of [Apache Apex](http://apex.incubator.apache.org/) platform. This tool copies data from different sources like HDFS, shared drive, NFS, FTP, Kafka to different destinations. Copying data from remote HDFS cluster to local HDFS cluster is supported by dtIngest. dtIngest runs yarn jobs to copy data in parallel fashion, so it's very fast. It takes care of failure handling, recovery etc. and supports polling directories periodically to do continious copy.

Usage: dtingest [OPTION]... SOURCEURL... DESTINATIONURL
example: dtingest hdfs://nn1:8020/source hdfs://nn2:8020/dest

Answer (score 1):

It's also useful to note that you can run the underlying MapReduce jobs with either the source or target cluster like so:

```
hadoop --config /path/to/hadoop/config distcp <src> <dst>
```

Comment: I am getting while trying to copy ... Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

distcp command use for copying from one cluster to another cluster in parallel. You have to set the path for namenode of src and path for namenode of dst, internally it use mapper.

Example:

```
$ hadoop distcp <src> <dst>
```

there few options you can set for distcp

**-m** for no. of mapper for copying data this will increase speed of copying.

**-atomic** for auto commit the data.

**-update** will only update data that is in old version.

There are generic command for copying files in hadoop are -cp and -put but they are use only when the data volume is less.

Comment: I am getting while trying to copy ... Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)