# Copy directory recursively from one Hadoop cluster to another

Tags: hadoop, copy, hdfs, cluster-computing, mirror

How can I copy a directory recursively from cluster1 to cluster2 in Hadoop HDFS?  The outcome I would like is a directory structure mirrored with data.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in tool distcp :

bash$ hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/foo/bar \ hdfs://nn2:8020/bar/foo

See the documentation here : [Distcp tool](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html)

Comment: No, it will do the the copy of the directories as well as files récursively see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862904/how-to-copy-data-from-one-hdfs-to-another-hdfs